Error: Unnamed type used 'BOOL' in iOS project XCode
I am having project in XCode version: 15.4 using Swift for iOS development -> uiKit.
I have added the c++ class to my project.
MyStaticClass.h:
#ifndef MYSTATICCLASS_H
#define MYSTATICCLASS_H

class MyStaticClass {
public:
static bool isEven(int number);
};

#endif

MyStaticClass.cpp
#include "MyStaticClass.h"

#include <iostream>

bool MyStaticClass::isEven(int number) {return (number % 2 == 0);}

Then i created wrapper for this class in objective C as
//  MyStaticClass_Wrapper.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyStaticClassWrapper : NSObject

+ (BOOL)isEven:(int)number;

@end

//  MyStaticClass_Wrapper.mm
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "MyStaticClass_Wrapper.h"
#include "MyStaticClass.h"

@implementation MyStaticClassWrapper

+ (BOOL)isEven:(int)number {
  // Uncomment the line below to use the C++ implementation
  // return MyStaticClass::isEven(number);
  return true;
  }

@end

**Note: ** The objective file is .mm not .m
I added the bridging Header file as:
#import "MyStaticClass_Wrapper.h"

and i added its path in Build Setting -> Objective-C Bridging Header
Added PrefixHeader.pch:
//  PrefixHeader.pch
//#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#import <Availability.h>

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

#endif

typedef enum{
bFileTypeDefault = 1,
bFileTypePhoto,
bFileTypeVideo,
bFileTypeAudio,
bFileTypeDocuments,
} baseFileType;

BOOL \_isFakeAccount;

#endif

then added the prefix header path to Build Setting -> Prefix Header in setting.
when i build it:
Error : Unnamed type used 'BOOL'
when i uncomment "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>"
Error : Along with Unnamed type used 'BOOL' .... 'NSString' also encounters same error
How to resolve it, am stucked with this error.
i tried commenting the BOOl, creating .m file to declare global variable seperately.
Didn't worked.
When i comment .pch file content it works fine.

what happens when you put the #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> inside the #if OBJC section?   If there are straight C or C++ files being compiled they may not know what BOOL or other ObjC stuff is.

Thankyou, the error was resolved by putting all objective c guards and code inside the #if OBJC section

The .pch file is prepended to every file you compile (c, c++, or objc) for that target, so if you are importing an ObjC header, it should be inside the #ifdef __OBJC__ section.  Otherwise the import will be unknown to non-objc files being compiled.  Foundation/Foundation.h is an ObjC specific header.
